# dynamically hardcode checkbox, dictionary into .cs

Tags: c#, wpf

This question is about programming approach. I just began developing wpf in c# not long ago and need some help here. Basically right now i have 2 files - 1.Text file call it(Textfile) and 2. Xml file.

My program approach is as below:

1. Run the program (this program contains hard-coded checkboxes)
2. Do an xml parsing. I have a dictionary with values and keys hard-coded. If xml's attribute's descendants do not contain these values, new checkboxes will be created in a stackpanel of the program.
3. Do a "Textfile" parsing. Using the "Textfile" as discussed earlier on, if i have certain strings in the textfile, i will check or uncheck the hard-coded checkboxes
4. Build button event. Users will then manually edit as they wish(check or uncheck whichever checkbox they like) and click on the "build" button and this event will write the new copy of "Textfile". If checkbox were checked, individual strings will be written.

So let's call a new target found in the xml file as "Exec_newtarget". So what i need to do is this:

1. Run the program
2. Do xml parsing. Compare with dictionary values and keys, if the value "Exec_newtarget" do not exist, this will be hard-coded into the dictionary object in the .cs file and "Exec_newtarget" checkbox will be created in the .cs file
3. Do a "Textfile" parsing. This will check or uncheck the hard-coded checkboxes
4. Build button event. New "Textfile" will be written and if the "Exec_newtarget" checkbox is checked, "Exec_newtarget" will be written as a string into the "Textfile"
5. Run the program again
6. Do xml parsing (To check for new targets such as "Exec_nexttarget")
7. Do Texfile parsing. This time since "Exec_newtarget" was written previously (as in 4.), "Exec_newtarget" will be checked
8. Build button event writes a new "Textfile"
   ...
   ...
   rinse and repeat

So my question is, is it possible to dynamically hardcode dictionary values, keys and checkboxes into .cs file? if so how should i do it. Or is there a better way for my program to work?

Edit 1:
Here i will explain to you why I am doing this.

1. My project is to automate manual processes. Previously users have to go to this "Textfile" and choose the appropriate targets they need and edit manually. For example, if they need "Exec_newtarget", they will go to "#Exec_newtarget" and remove "#". There are over 40 such strings to be edited and it can be a hassle to do it individually.
2. The main process is to run a bat file. When the bat file is executed, the strings found in "Textfile" which will essentially be found in the xml file then perform processes as needed. This xml file is constantly updated with new attributes and descendants.
3. To maintain the structure of .the xml file as well as to simplify things, a copy of the "Textfile" is generated automatically instead of manually adding new strings into the "Textfile"

Comment: I think you would getter some better answers if you explain your reasons for doing this. There is nothing wrong with generating code, but maybe there is a better way of doing this that you may not have thought of.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your approach is a bit overcomplicated. But it may just be my understanding.

First of all, look into [DataBinding in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx). That removes GUI from the equation because GUI is updated automatically based on the data you bind to it (really good stuff).

Second you want to controll the dictionaries/datastructures. If I am reading your problem correctly you would first load all XML into the dictionary, then you can add any missing "hardcoded" values to the dictionary (possibly with empty value?). These missing keys could be read from a separate .txt-file that you include in your app. Or even be a coma-separated setting in App.Config. (Avoid hardcoding)

Comment: As i am new to the project, it states the requirement of having a graphical user interface. Therefore i have to strictly comply to the requirements. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: The third paragraph should still apply without WPF. There is no direct requirement between them. :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you would like to have self-changing code. In general, this is possible. However, it is complex and for your case not the nicest way of creating some checkboxes.

What you could do instead is have your program which contains a List of checkboxes. This list could be parsed from your xml file (you just need one file). In this file you can store the checkbox-names as well as the values.

Using such a solution has the advantage that you only need one external file instead of two and you don't need to have self-changing code.

Comment: Hi Christian, just a question, because currently i do hard-code and with hard-code of checkboxes, i am able to do some xml serialization. is it possible to do xml serialization with the list being used? also, am i right to say that this list will be an external file? be it text or xml file?

Comment: I think I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. As far as I understand, you would like to have a WPF application that shows n CheckBoxes. The names of the checkboxes and their checked value (true, false) is stored in a xml file. All you need is a WPF application that reads the xml file and shows all those checkboxes. Then you check / uncheck the boxes in your app and by clicking Save, all the values are stored back to the xml file. If that is what you want to do, then you don't need additional files.

Comment: All you need is an IList<CheckBox> (list of checkboxes) in your application which gets filled from the xml file.